# How can I stream data from a file within a gzip archive so that I can test the header?

Tags: go, gzip, tar

I am trying to write an extraction tool, in Go, which will decompress/extract several types of archive files. To check the type of file, I am making use of the magic numbers, and have been successful in checking for `.gz` and `.tar` archives directly, but for any `.tar.gz`/`.tgz` archives, I do not seem to be able to check the tar file within the Gzip bundle.

My current train of thought is that I need to take the output of `gzip.NewReader(f)` and feed pull the header of its output, but this is not working.

```
f, err := os.Open(file)
if err != null {
  return fmt.Errorf("problem opening %s", filename)
}
r, _ := gzip.NewReader(f)
h, err := GetHeader(r, l)
```

Here, `GetHeader` is...

```
func GetHeader(r io.Reader, l uint32) (in []byte, err error) {
    fmt.Println("Here C")
    in = make([]byte, l)
    n := 0
    n, err = io.ReadFull(r, in)
    if err != nil && err != io.EOF && err != io.ErrUnexpectedEOF {
        fmt.Println("Here D")
        return nil, err
    }
    fmt.Println(n)
    in = in[:n]
    return in, nil
}
```

It is used for both checking the Gzip and Tar archive on their own successfully, and in all, `l` is set to `uint32 3072`.

I can only assume that I'm missing something pretty trivial here, but at the minute I'm at a loss.

If there is anyone that can assist me with this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is the correct approach, but "this is not working" isn't a helpful problem description. That being said, you almost certainly want to use a bufio.Reader here, so you can [Peek](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Reader.Peek) at the first N bytes without consuming them. [http.DetectContentType](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#DetectContentType) may be useful too.

Comment: @Peter I already limit as a part of the GetHeader, where it will only take the maximum number of bytes from input (`l`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
h, err := GetHeader(r, l)
```

instead of

```
h, err := GetHeader(f, l)
```

Comment: Well spotted, I'd looked at the wrong line of code when I copied it. I am indeed using `h, err := GetHeader(r, l)` and not `h, err := GetHeader(f, l)`. I've updated my original post to reflect this.

Comment: But did it solve the problem? If not, what do you observe when you run the code?

Comment: So updating to this actually worked perfectly. I think that I'd gotten myself confused while working on it pretty late before, and started going around in circles. Sometimes it just takes a second set of eyes to spot it!